# It's possible to make foreach loop like this in postgre?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pdo, foreach

I want to calculate something using only pdo, wihout php.
My query will look something like this:

```
WITH first_query as (
    SELECT date FROM users 
    WHERE user_id = 258; 
), second_query as (
   SELECT SUM(posts) FROM activity 
   WHERE date > (SELECT * FROM first_query)
   AND user_id = 258;
) 
SELECT user_id, date, first_time, (SELECT * FROM first_query), (SELECT * FROM second_query)
FROM users WHERE user_id = 258;
```

What I want, to execute this query, foreach user from this query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users 
WHERE country = 'PL';
```

Example: 
users from query = 1, 4, 6, 66, 676, 34, 678, 234;
foreach this user, execute:

```
WITH first_query as (
    SELECT date FROM users 
    WHERE user_id = 258; 
), second_query as (
   SELECT SUM(posts) FROM activity 
   WHERE date > (SELECT * FROM first_query)
   AND user_id = 258;
) 
SELECT user_id, date, first_time, (SELECT * FROM first_query), (SELECT * FROM second_query)
FROM users WHERE user_id = 258;
```

where user_id is this from query.
It is possible to make this in query?

Maybe I will show how result will be look in php:

```
$users = 'select user_id from useres where something' // result as array

foreach ($users as $user_id) {
// execute query

    WITH first_query as (
        SELECT date FROM users 
        WHERE user_id = $user_id; 
    ), second_query as (
       SELECT SUM(posts) FROM activity 
       WHERE date > (SELECT * FROM first_query)
       AND user_id = $user_id;
    ) 
    SELECT user_id, date, first_time, (SELECT * FROM first_query), (SELECT * FROM second_query)
    FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id;

}
```

I want to make identical loop in pdo.

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want the query to do.  You have constructs such as `select *` where a scalar subquery is needed -- something that you should never be using in that context.

Comment: Question edited :).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the sum of posts after a certain date for a given set of users.  This is more easily phrased as a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Assuming that `users.user_id` is unique (which really needs to be true for your query to work at all):

```
 SELECT u.*, SUM(a.posts)
 FROM users u JOIN
      activity a         
      ON a.user_id = u.user_id AND a.date > u.date
 WHERE u.user_id IN (1, 4, 6, 66, 676, 34, 678, 234)
 GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

Or, more specifically:

```
 SELECT u.*, SUM(a.posts)
 FROM users u JOIN
      activity a         
      ON a.user_id = u.user_id AND a.date > u.date
 WHERE u.country = 'PL'
 GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: You are right, but in some case it will be inpossible to use JOIN. Im wondering, how to pass user_id, for every subquery that will by used (first_query, second_query and many others), like in php foreach loop :).